# Looping an AnimationSet causes StackOverflowError

Tags: android, loops, kotlin, android-animation, stack-overflow

I am delevolping an android app in which I have an infinitely repeating animation that is causing a StackOverflowError. It does this, when another animation on the same object is started.

```
private fun pulse() {
    val randomGenerator = Random()

    val durationx = randomGenerator.nextInt(4000) + 1500

    val inflateX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentView, "scaleX", 1.3f).apply {
        duration = durationx.toLong()
    }
    val inflateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentView, "scaleY", 1.3f).apply {
        duration = durationx.toLong()
    }
    val deflateX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentView, "scaleX", 1.0f).apply {
        duration = durationx.toLong()
    }
    val deflateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentView, "scaleY", 1.0f).apply {
        duration = durationx.toLong()
    }
    val rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentView, "rotation", 1.0f).apply {
        duration = durationx.toLong()
    }
    val soulToButton = AnimatorSet().apply {
        play(inflateX).with(inflateY)
        play(rotate).with(inflateX)
        play(deflateX).after(inflateX)
        play(deflateY).after(inflateY)
        start()
    }

    soulToButton.addListener(object: AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
            soulToButton.start() // stacktrace points to this line as cause for the error.
        }
    })
    soulToButton.start()

    AnimatorSet().apply {
        play(soulToButton)
        start()
    }
}
```

I tried changing the function to `fun pulse(stop: boolean)`, calling `pulse(false)` for starting the pulse and `pulse(true)` before the other animation starts, and adding `if (stop) {soulToButton.cancel()}` in several places. I also tried wrapping the line causing the error like this: `while(stop == false){soultoButton.start()}`

All of this didn´t help.

Comment: Just tried to reproduce on an empty project setup with only this piece of code - runs without any exception. Any clue as to how one can reproduce it?

Comment: 1. how many places are you calling pulse function ? may be exact scenario can help.
2. last three lines of code should be removed as it is creating extra animatorset . 3. As described in answers, you should use repeatcount as infinite instead of calling soulToButton animatorset again on end of animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this version: its short and concise and basically doing the same thing.

```
    val randomGenerator = Random()

    val durationx = randomGenerator.nextInt(4000) + 1500

    val animator = animator@{ property : String, value : Float ->
        return@animator ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContextView, property, value).apply {
            duration = durationx.toLong()
            repeatMode = REVERSE
            repeatCount = INFINITE
        }
    }

    AnimatorSet().apply {
        playTogether(animator("scaleX", 1.3f),animator("scaleY", 1.3f),animator("rotation", 45.0f))
        start()
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is Kotlin but it is still Java and all the JVM limitations are relevant here. Thus you cannot call one function indefinitely without causing StackOverflowError since the JVM stack is limited.

There are special functions that will help you to run the animation indefinitely. For example

```
objectAnimator.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
```

Or in your case

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentView, "scaleX", 1.3f).apply {
        duration = durationx.toLong()
        repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
    }
```

After you modify all your animations the same way and chain them in `AnimatorSet` its `start` function will play this animation indefinite time without StackOverflowError.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to start animation again after it has completed in here ,

```
soulToButton.addListener(object: AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
            soulToButton.start() // This will start the animation again without an end to the animation hence the StackOverflow error.
        }
    })
```

In order to run an animation for infinite time use the following piece of code,

```
val inflateX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mContentView, "scaleX", 1.3f).apply {
        duration = durationx.toLong()
        repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
        }

val soulToButton = AnimatorSet().apply {
        play(inflateX).with(inflateY)
        play(rotate).with(inflateX)
        play(deflateX).after(inflateX)
        play(deflateY).after(inflateY)

    }

soulToButton.start()
```