# Repeat an Animation with a delay between each loop on Android

Tags: android, loops, animation, android-animation, stack-overflow

I have an animation to wiggle a button. I want it repeat infinitely with a delay between each loop.

I tried using `doOnEnd` with a `startDelay` and it worked well, but [eventually caused a StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967447/looping-an-animationset-causes-stackoverflowerror).

**Using doOnEnd with startDelay (works but causes SO error):**

```
val animator = ObjectAnimator
    .ofFloat(premiumButton, "translationX", 0F, 25F, -25F, 25F, -25F, 15F, -15F, 6F, -6F, 0F)
    .setDuration(2000L)

animator.doOnEnd {
    it.startDelay = 10000
    it.start()
}

animator.start()
```

Next I tried using an `AnimatorSet` but my animations are different durations and so it just jiggles continuously without a delay between jiggles no matter what configuration/properties I use (since the jiggle is the shorter animation).

**Using AnimatorSet (didn't work because animations are different durations):**

```
val animatorJiggle = ObjectAnimator
    .ofFloat(myButton, "translationX", 0F, 25F, -25F, 25F, -25F, 15F, -15F, 6F, -6F, 0F)
    .setDuration(2000)
    .apply { repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE }

val animatorDelay = ObjectAnimator
    .ofFloat(myButton, "translationX", 0F)
    .setDuration(10000)
    .apply { repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE }

AnimatorSet().apply {
    playSequentially(animatorJiggle, animatorDelay)
    // repeat(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE) { }
    start()
}
```

How do I get an animation to loop with a delay between each loop without using the first solution (since it causes an SO error)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the the `pause` and `resume` functions of the `ObjectAnimator` with coroutines. Basically, I pause the animations, wait for the delay, then resume. I don't know if this will cause a StackOverflow error, but I don't think so.

**Repeat animation with a delay:**

```
private fun ObjectAnimator.repeatWithDelay(delay: Long, lifecycleScope: LifecycleCoroutineScope) {
    repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
    doOnRepeat {
        pause() // pause animator
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
            delay(delay)
            resume() // resume animator
        }
    }
}
```

**Using it (inside an activity):**

```
val jiggleAnimator = ObjectAnimator
    .ofFloat(myButton, "translationX", 0F, 25F, -25F, 25F, -25F, 15F, -15F, 6F, -6F, 0F)
    .setDuration(2000)

jiggleAnimator.repeatWithDelay(10000, this@MyActivity.lifecycleScope)
jiggleAnimator.start()
```

You could also [use a timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61686127/599535) or a runnable, but I chose to use coroutines because it's safer (you can make sure you're not trying access the UI or variables of an activity after its been killed).

Comment: What if you don't have access to a lifecycle scope?

Comment: You could use a timer or a runnable instead of coroutines with a lifecycle scope.

Comment: I could, but then the runnable/coroutine wouldn't be tied to any lifecycle. Wouldn't that be risking a memory leak?